# About submitting a HTML form

Tags: html

There is a HTML form which has some text input fields and 2 buttons, say Yes and No. Instead of accessing the URL first and then filling up the form, how can I fill up those text fields which I need to fill and do the action of either one of the buttons in a single URL?

E.g. Take this form for example: there are 2 fields text1 and text2.

http://www.mysite.com?text1=value1&text2=value2

In the above e.g.(hope that is right) how to add the button action also, is my question.
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Typically YES/NO choices are represented with a pair of radio buttons. These values would automatically be sent back with the form submission, based on the name of the radio buttons.

Comment: I just gave Yes or No just for an example. Buttons will have values like Submit with inputs and Submit without inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Use submit inputs instead of buttons.

```
<form>
<input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Yes" />
<input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="No" />
</form>
```

Then you can grab what button the user pressed to send the form using PHP, JSP, ASP or whatever is your server-side language.

Comment: I though it submits the value of this submit-button only if user clicks on the button with mouse, not when the form is submitted by enter. But now I am thinking, it actually makes sense to click on it, using enter would not select "yes" or "no" anyway.

Comment: Oh, you're right. It won't send the submit-input's value if the user don't click it. @Diodeus' idea seems the more viable.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible unless you have control over the file displaying the form.  If you do have control over that file I can show you how with JavaScript.  It would make much more sense to use the serverside language filling the form in though.

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. The reason I want to fill the text fields and the button action all through in one URL is that I'm using this through lynx command in a shell script. So just to get the desired output I need to specify all this as an exact URL. To be exact, I want to know the changed URL after this submit action. Hope I'm clear. How can this be done? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done through javascript:

Put input type=hidden in your form, and fill the value with a button and submit right after that.

```
<form name="name_of_form" action="" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="button_value" value=""  id="hidden_value" />
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:submit_form('yes');">Yes</button>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:submit_form('no');">No</button>
</form>
```

And add this JS function at the top somewhere

```
function submit_form(yesno)
{
    document.getElementById('hidden_value').value=yesno;
    document.name_of_form.submit();
}
```

note: Although it should work, I can't tell for sure, cause i suck at JS.